# CSS not showing with AngularJS 1.6.4

Tags: css, angularjs, cordova

I am working on Cordova and Angular JS for mobile app dev but I encountered difficulties with CSS class which is not being displayed as expected.
1) The CSS code in a style.css file:

```
  .nav .active {
    border-top: 3px solid #11a7ab; }
```

2) JS controller code NavCtrl.js (I have 2 tabs HOME and ABOUT), here I initialize the home tab:

```
function NavCtrl($scope){

    $scope.menu = 'home';

}
```

3) The html code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header">
            My app
        </header>

        <section ng-view class="view">
        </section>

        <nav class="nav" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
            <a href="#home" ng-click="menu = 'home'" ng-class="{'active': menu=='home'}"><i class="icon-home"></i></a>
            <a href="#about" ng-click="menu = 'about'" ng-class="{'active': menu=='about'}"><i class="icon-about"></i></a>
        </nav> 


        </script>
             <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
             <script src="js/angular-1.6.4.js"></script>
             <script src="js/controller/NavCtrl.js"></script>
             <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that when I use AngularJS v1.1.5 the code worked without any problem but when I used AngularJS v1.6.4 the CSS "active" is not showing up. Did I miss something on the configuration for the code to work correctly with AngularJS v1.6.4 ?

Comment: You should be loading your app.js before your NavCtrl .js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show us your app.js but it looks like you didn't register your controller into the current module of your app as seen in the official doc:
             `angular.module('controllerAsExample', [])
      .controller('SettingsController1', SettingsController1);`

And also replace $scope by this and use ng-controller="YourController as vm" ... {{vm.yourVar}}

Have a look at the 1.6 best practices which is more oriented to component architecture. We don't rely on  $scope anymore but on class encapsulation to handle scope variables

Comment: hi guys, worked like a charm. Thank you Julon. You indication helped me a lot.I create the controller into the app.js and work nicely now.

Comment: Please select it as the correct answer if it helped you :)